# drawing line from points

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, c#, line

I have a series of XY coordinates. I want to use these points to draw a line in ArcMap using ArcObjects 10.1 with c#. I have saved this in a table inside geodatabase.

Am i supposed to create a feature class for this purpose or should i use graphics?

I am looking for an ArcObjects solution not Python.